# How to find International Internet Radio Stations on Windows Media Player or Winamp?

Tags: internet-radio

I tried both apps and can't find any single station by country or region (taiwan or taipei).  The search on Windows Media Player didn't yield any result, and Winamp pointed to [www.shoutcast.com](http://www.shoutcast.com) but there, it doesn't seem it can search by country or region.  Is there a way on these apps?  It would seem reasonable to at least find a few of them.  (on the page below, there were at least 25 of them).

Here is a list of the sample radio stations in Taiwan and I tried some and they are playable even using Google Chrome (it used to be IE was needed to play them).

http://tunein.com/radio/Taiwan-r101302/

But I was wonder if WMP or Winamp or even VLC has a tool to find by region so we don't need to use random webpages to find them, because if it is on WMP or Winamp, there might be a more uniform user interface to find any radio station in different countries or regions.

**Update: actually, I found that tunein.com actually has a lot of radio stations in Taiwan, Hong Kong, and even Chinese stations in the Silicon Valley.  So it might be a somewhat de facto place to looking for stations.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMP had a search by region and language on WMP9 for example, I go to Radio tuner, select Internet radio, and somewhat hidden in the bottom of the quick list is "Search for Radio Station" in there you can search by music genre , language and country/region.  But it still comes up with Nothing for your needs.

^ this same thing works in WMP12 also

In that situation I would ignore the stuff that comes with the OS, and get a configurable net radio player, and fill the list with what I wanted.

Comment: I think Microsoft might have abandoned Windows Media Player... I can't imagine that to get to the menu bar, the method is to right click on the bar where the top-left corner "LEFT" and "RIGHT" arrow is... that's very non-intuitive... if PC and Mac both stole Xerox's design of using the GUI, the hidding of the menubar is almost the opposite of it

Comment: good point, they sure didnt improve it for users, more like improved it for marketeers.   They also concentrated on the "media center", with many of the same things, but different. splitting off thier efforts to it might have made differences. It has even more stuff in it, of both types.